# Spring web flow with dart on frontend and backend

Tags: spring, web-applications, dart

Anyone tried using spring web framework with dart
kindly provide me with an example or if you have seen one in Github i would appreciate the link , have searched but i havent got one

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately I don't think you can accomplish whatever it is you are trying to accomplish. dart, as tagged here is the dart programming language which runs in its own virtual machine or is compiled to javascript. It has no connection to Java or Java Server Pages at all.

If you are using Dart on the front end, any back-end server an serve the html and dart/javascript scripts and respond to any ajax requests you setup, but you cannot integrate Spring Web Flow, a Java Server backend, with a dart backend.